# Is this approach to Django multiple settings files reasonable?

Tags: python, django

## Question

Is my approach to multiple Django settings.py files below reasonable (transparent, safe, etc.)?

### My Approach

I have a `settings.py` and a `settings_local.py`. `settings.py` is under version control and a `settings_local.py` is NOT under version control. At the end of `settings.py` it tries to import `settings_local.py` if it's available.

My theory to this approach is that I can leave my default / safe settings under `settings.py` and simply push to production to deploy. On deploy, `settings_local.py` won't be present and its local-only settings are not used. However, when working locally `settings_local.py` is present and its local-only settings are used.

#### settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
# other settings...

try:
    from settings_local import *
except ImportError:
   pass
```

#### settings_local.py

```
from settings import *

DEBUG = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)
# other settings...
```

My concern about this approach is that they both import the other. I don't think this qualifies as a circular import but as an indicator that under different circumstances one would consider combining these files.

The reason `settings_local.py` imports `settings.py` is so I can add to already defined variables while observing DRY principles e.g. add a new entry to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` without completely redefining it.

Thanks!

---

## Solution

Ultimately, I abandoned the above outlined approach. It was an interesting and informative process for me to try solving this problem, however, my amalgamated approach just has too many drawbacks.

For folks finding this in the future, the most appropriate approach is likely one of the solutions as outlined in the [wiki page on this topic](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) as kindly pointed out by @DrTyrsa and @Mark Lavin, thanks!

Comment: What I usually do is have the local settings be `settings.py` (not in version control) and then have a `settings_base.py` in version control (and, actually, also a `settings_dev.py` and `settings_server.py` with non-sensitive settings that are useful to track; these import from `settings_base`). This avoids the quasi-circular import, but it means that on a new checkout you always have to remember to do e.g. `echo 'from settings_dev import *' > settings.py`.

Comment: And also you can look at [existing approaches](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) before inventing your own.

Comment: @Dougal thanks, I'll consider this approach as well.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I have looked that over, thanks for sharing. This approach is an amalgam of the ones presented there. My approach here seemed to fit my project and personal logic, however, I'm very open to it not being a good approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this is a common approach it is not a good approach. I have used this type of configuration in the past and since abandoned it. The problem comes when you have multiple developers working together or when you are deploying to multiple environments (i.e. staging and production). You have the choice of either

1. Make `settings.py` the production settings. Then each developer must override settings to setup their local environment (DB settings, `DEBUG=True`, adding `debug_toolbar`, etc). Since this is not in source control it is repeated work and leads to "it works on my machine" kinds of problems.
2. Make `settings.py` the development settings. Now you have meaningful pieces of your production configuration in `local_settings.py` which **is not in source control**. This makes deployment messy. Obviously you don't want to put sensitive information in the source control.

Adding a staging environment just makes this worse. I much prefer the [Simple Package Organization for Environments](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments) described in the SplitSettings wiki.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Mark. I think you're right, my approach is not a good solution. I've learned quite a bit attempting this, however, the most DRY solution (as you've pointed out) would be to use an existing popular one :)

Comment: As an update @Mark Lavin, I've been using your recommended "Simple Package Organization for Environments" approach and it is quite simple and transparent. Thanks!

Comment: "Simple Package Organization for Environments" approach is simple and useful, thanks for your answer..