# Django 1.4 (MEDIA_ROOT, STATIC_ROOT, TEMPLATE_DIRS)

Tags: django

I have a **Django 1.3** project with this options in **settings.py**

> SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**__*file*__**))
>
> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
>
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
>
> TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
>       os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'), )

But in **Django 1.4** by default **settings.py** is moved in subdirectory with name that is equal to project name. Because of that **static**, **media** and **templates** directories now have to be moved in the same subdirectory?

Is this what I have to do, or just change STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_ROOT and TEMPLATE_DIRS options?

I know that both variants are OK, but what is best practice for this in Django 1.4?

And also I know that every app can have it's own templates and static directories.

And is it better to put all other application directories inside the same subdirectory? This is not what is happening by default using manage.py startapp

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Comment: I saw this but don't think it answer my questions. They just say its possible to use with both ways

Comment: Oh ok. Well it'd be best to put all relevant *operational* code under `myproject/myproject` and then have `myproject/tests`, `myproject/docs` etc. As for the static/media, it depends, I usually want my apps to be autonomous/pluggable, so every one of my apps has its own 'static'  folder.

Comment: What about 404.html? Where to put this template file? And what about media directory which is one for the whole project?

Comment: For both cases, I almost always have a `website` app in my project with an empty `models.py`. That app houses an *index* view(inside its `views.py`), since sometimes its hard to tell which app should have the index('/') view! Also this app has a `templates` folder, which has the 404/500 pages. Same goes for the universal media files of my projects.

Comment: Very interesting solution, can you write it as answer so I can vote up and eventually accept it as more accurate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK the scheme that I follow is this:

`myproject/requirements.txt` - pip installable packages

`myproject/deployment` - Deployment stuff like server config files, fixtures(dummy data), etc.

`myproject/docs`       - project's docs

`myproject/tests`      - project's tests

`myproject/myproject`  - project's operational code(and settings.py, urls.py)

*Expanding* `myproject/myproject` folder:

`myproject/myproject/app1`  - a regular app(encompassing its specific templates/static files)

`myproject/myproject/app2`  - another regular app(same as above)

`myproject/myproject/website` - semi special app, by convention.

This `website` app houses basically 4 things:

1) an empty `models.py`(so that django will consider it as a valid app)

2) a `views.py` with the entry point `index` view. Maybe some other views that don't fit in any other specific app.

3) a `management` dir with custom [django commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/) which apply to the whole project.

4) a `templates` dir that has the 404.html and 505.html. Also it has a subdir called `website` that includes universal/base html templates that every other app `extends`, plus
the `index.html`.

5) a `static`  dir with subsequent subdirs named `css`, `js` and `media` for global static files.

Nothing exotic I guess. I think that most people follow a similar pattern, but I would like to here any inefficiencies with this, if any.

**EDIT:**
with regards to settings for production VS development I use
the popular settings_local pattern, which you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285406/is-this-approach-to-django-multiple-settings-files-reasonable) and eventually will
lead you [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments), which describes a better pattern.

Comment: What do you do for different settings for local/dev/test/QA/UAT/production environments, using this setup? Have you considered placing separate settings underneath the deployment directory?

Comment: @Jordan I do what most people did up until recently. I have a settings_local.py on the same level as settings.py. Then settings.py does `try: from settings_local import * except:pass`. settings_local.py is of course ignored by my VCS. I think that there are alternative and better solutions out there though nowadys. It's a whole subject on its own.

Comment: I also do the same as rantanplan